# Android Developing App crashes on startup

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I currently develop an application which contains a custom `ListView`. I developed a custom array adapter.
I think my app crashes here:

```
ListView DirectoryView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fileListView);
```

So i think the error is in the activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/fileListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

Here is my LogCat:

```
09-09 11:19:21.254: E/Trace(1152): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-09 11:19:21.484: D/AndroidRuntime(1152): Shutting down VM
09-09 11:19:21.484: W/dalvikvm(1152): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.teamdroid.explorer/com.teamdroid.explorer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.teamdroid.explorer.listDirectory.getDirectory(listDirectory.java:20)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at com.teamdroid.explorer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-09 11:19:21.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     ... 11 more
```

Please can you help me. I am searching this error for 2 day.
thanks!

**EDIT:**
I have a third file which lists a directory in this `listview`:

```
    public class listDirectory extends ListActivity {

    String[] DirList;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(icicle);
    }   

    public void getDirectory (){
        MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
        String path = main.getPath();

        ListView DirectoryView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fileListView);
        CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), DirList);

        File file = new File(path);
        File[] FileList = file.listFiles();

        java.util.Arrays.sort(FileList);

        for(int i = 0; i < FileList.length; i++){
            if(FileList[i].isDirectory()){
                DirList[i] = (FileList[i].getName() + " [folder]");
            } else{
                DirList[i] = (FileList[i].getName() + " [file]");
            }
         }

         DirectoryView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I think in this file is the error.

Comment: have you set `setContentView(R.layout.main)` where R.layout.main is your own layout which contains the listview ?

Comment: The activity_main.xml contains the ListView. And in the MainActivity.java i set setContentView(R.layout.activity_main). I have a third file which lists a directory in this listview.

Comment: you got to write `super.onCreate(icicle);` as a first statement in your `onCreate` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you did not set content view inside onCreate() method and therefor findViewById is unable to find view objects and so returns null.

Assume that your XML layout file is my_layout.xml. Inside onCreate(...) add this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very confusing code...

I think in your `MainActivity` you new a instance of `listDirectory`, this does not get `listDirectory.onCreate()` called, so content view is null.
so `findViewById()` inside `listDirectory.getDirectory()` finds view in listDirectory's content view not MainActivity's which is null and cause NPE